# Is is possible to format a specific part of an string within objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Is it possible to format a section of text in a string within the actual code of xcode to be displayed in a single label? For instance make a specific word bold while leaving the rest normal.

Or do I have to use separate strings with different labels with the specific formatting already determined?

Comment: [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use attributed text. Example below bolds the word posted By but not the name

```
 NSString *format = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"Posted By: %@", @"Details Screen", @"posted by %@");
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, name];
const CGFloat fontSize = 14.0;
UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:fontSize];
UIFont *regularFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:fontSize];
UIColor *foregroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:(51.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];

// Create the attributes
NSDictionary *attrs = @{NSFontAttributeName: boldFont,
                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: foregroundColor};
NSDictionary *subAttrs = @{NSFontAttributeName: regularFont};

const NSRange range = NSMakeRange(text.length - name.length,name.length); // range of " Posted by: "

// Create the attributed string (text + attributes)
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text
                                       attributes:attrs];
[attributedText setAttributes:subAttrs range:range];

// Set it in our UILabel and we are done!
[_textLabel setAttributedText:attributedText];
```